# How to understand the symmetry of MMA's tensor

Tags: tensors, symmetry

```
tensor = {{{2, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{9, 2}, {2, 4}}};
TensorDimensions[tensor]
TensorSymmetry[tensor]
```

How can I understand the symmetry of the output `Symmetric[{1,2,3}]` above?

And I can't recover this tensor with `Symmetric[{1,2,3}]`:

```
SymmetrizedArray[{{1, 1, 1} -> 2, {1, 1, 2} -> 9, {2, 2, 2} -> 4}, {2,
    2, 2}, Symmetric[{1, 2, 3}]] // Normal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Symmetric[{1,2,3}]` means that all six permutations of `{1,2,3}` are symmetries of the tensor:

```
Equal[tensor, Transpose[tensor, #]] & /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

A 3-symmetric tensor in dimensions `{2,2,2}` has four independent components:

```
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{2, 2, 2}, Symmetric[{1, 2, 3}]]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}} *)
```

Hence you need to do:

```
SymmetrizedArray[{{1, 1, 1} -> 2, {1, 1, 2} -> 9, {1, 2, 2} -> 2, {2, 2, 2} -> 4}, {2, 2, 2}, Symmetric[{1, 2, 3}]] == tensor
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

In `SymmetrizedArray`, the expression `Symmetric[{1,2,3}]` means all permutations of any set of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd subscripts have the save value.  For example, the rule `{1,1,2} -> 9` would then apply to all 3 permutations of {1,1,2}.

As output in `TensorSymmetry[tensor]` example, `Symmetry[{1,2,3}]` means if two elements are indexed by a permutation of the same set of subscripts, the elements are equal.

To recover `tensor` using `SymmetrizedArray`, include the rule `{2,2,1} -> 2`.  That rule will also apply to the element indexed by {2,1,2} and the element indexed by {1,2,2}.

Note that `Symmetry[{1,2,3}]` can also be written `Symmetry[All]` in your example.